# adding a marker on a map with each location update

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an android app that gets my devices location and adds a marker. It also tracks the location and the marker moves. I want to add a marker on the map each time the location changes, so I can then draw a Polyline between them at a later date. I am not using firebase or a DBHelper. Just looking for a simple way to do it.

This is the onLocationChanged function

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    LocationMarker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCoordinates));
    float zoomLevel = 12.0f;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoordinates, zoomLevel));
```

}

This is my onCreate function

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);

    mOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("My Current Location")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Gets map fragment and allows map to display location
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

Is it possible to store the lat and long into an array and use the array to plot the points? I've been trying to get my head around it but there isn't a definitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a field variable:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in onLocationChanged do:

```
points.add(myCoordinates);
```

And then later when you want to create PolyLine do something like:

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
  .addAll(points)
  .width(5)
  .color(Color.RED));
```

The addAll method supports an Iterable type which the ArrayList implements.

Comment: How do I get it to then add a marker at each point? Basically have a Start location -> All other markers -> End Location?

Comment: Either add the marker in your onLocationChanged (mMap.addMarker()) or loop on list (for (LatLng pos : points) { mMap.addMarker())}.  If you just want to know how to add a marker: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker .

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `Polyline`, the documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline).

The builder for a `Polyline` expects `LatLng` objects. I'm not sure what you're currently doing but you can either store the `LatLng` objects from your `onLocationChanged` function in an array or store all `Markers` you place on the map in an array and call their `getLocation` function to get the `LatLng` objects you need for your `Polyline`.